# Buttons and links keyboard triggers

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility, keyboard-events, wai-aria

While doing research I came across [this statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role):

> Warning: Be careful when marking up links with the button role.
>   Buttons are expected to be triggered using the <kbd>Space key</kbd>, while links
>   are expected to be triggered using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

1. Does anyone know why a different key is used for buttons / links?
2. Is it ok to trigger using both <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Before reading this I, as a user, would have had no idea when to use <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Had a quick look at Google to see what they do.

- For *links* <kbd>Space</kbd> scrolls down and <kbd>Enter</kbd> triggers
- For *buttons* both <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Buttons are form elements.**

   If you select a `checkbox` element, <kbd>space</kbd> will toggle the checkbox while <kbd>enter</kbd> will submit the form.

   So to be coherent, buttons act the same way. In practice, they accept both <kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> without any difference.
2. **It is not only ok but you have to**

   Read inside the [Third rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#third):

   > For example, if using role=button the element must be able to receive focus and a user must be able to activate the action associated with the element **using both the enter (on WIN OS) or return (MAC OS) and the space key.**
3. This is for historical reason, not that it has been defined in any official recommendation, as far as I know

   For instance an old bug from 2000 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56495) already stated that space bar was expected to work on buttons. Maybe an inheritance from Windows behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating to answer #1, but I believe the keys used to activate buttons versus hyperlinks are holdovers from operating systems. For hyperlinks, think of Windows Help in Windows 95 and its reliance on in-content links, or Hypercard on the Mac prior to that. Also note that `Space` has scrolled a page in browsers since (IIRC) day one.

To answer number 2, no it is not OK. This is because a space bar triggers a page scroll and many users expect that when focus is on a hyperlink that pressing `Space` will just scroll the page.

In short, honor the keyboard mappings that are in place since there are users who rely on them and messing with them can have catastrophic consequences for users of assistive tech along with users with disabilities who do not use assistive tech.

Let me re-state what you saw at Mozilla:

> A hyperlink can be fired by pressing the enter key. But a true button can be fired by pressing the enter key or the space bar. When a hyperlink has focus and the user presses the space bar, the page will scroll one screenful.

And then let me add this:

> I think it’s also worth mentioning that events triggered by a space bar only fire when the key is released, whereas using the Enter key will fire the event as soon as you press the key down (prior to releasing it).

Source: [Links, Buttons, Submits, and Divs, Oh Hell](http://adrianroselli.com/2016/01/links-buttons-submits-and-divs-oh-hell.html).